# CodeIgniter Active-Record Search with WHERE, AND, OR

Tags: codeigniter, search, activerecord

I'm using CI's active record to generation a query result. This is the meat of the query produced:

```
WHERE manufacturers.name = 'Ford'
OR dealer_email LIKE '%Ford%'
OR dealer_name LIKE '%Ford%'
OR dealer_contact = 'Ford'
OR dealer_city = 'Ford'
OR regions.name = 'Ford'
OR states.state_name = 'Ford'
AND `dealer_city` IN ('Atlanta')
```

I want just the Ford dealers in Atlanta. The result returns all Ford dealers and all dealers in Atlanta. I don't understand where my logic is wrong. PS: The extra OR statements are part of a broad search for "Ford", because it could also be name or contact IN Atlanta and it's typed into a search box.

Comment: you need parentheses surrounding the OR statements. maybe also include your codeigniter code so that people can suggest how to fix it to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
WHERE (manufacturers.name = 'Ford'
OR dealer_email LIKE '%Ford%'
OR dealer_name LIKE '%Ford%'
OR dealer_contact = 'Ford'
OR dealer_city = 'Ford'
OR regions.name = 'Ford'
OR states.state_name = 'Ford')
AND `dealer_city` IN ('Atlanta')
```